How to deal with short answers
To every tense we have so called short answer. For instance present simple has "Yes, I do" or "No, I don't"
What if someone says to me "Do you work there" and my response is "Yes, I work" not "Yes, I do"
Another example "Do you have to do it" and I answer "Yes, I have to" not "Yes, I do"?

What's the question? "What if someone says to me..." is not a question  What do you mean by "how to deal with short answers"? NOT my downvote.

For the first,  the right 'short answer' is 'Yes, I do', and for the second, both 'Yes, I have to', and 'Yes, I do'. are correct.

If your test wants you to use "do" then saying "I work" is 100% wrong. But more generally as a native speaker, "Do you work there?" "Yes, I work" is odd, because they're asking where you work - "Do you work there?" "Yes, I do" is much better.  There are a lot of similar questions about "do" already here if you know what to search for.

To add to that, if your answer is negative, there is a huge difference between saying "No, I don't" and "No, I don't work." It would not just be awkwardly phrased—it would have a completely different meaning. It means that you don't have a job at all.

The shortest answers are just "yes" and "no"

"Yes, I work" only tells the questioner that you have a job somewhere, not that you work 'there'.

This is a very interesting question for a learner. Sometimes I wonder if native speakers understand how difficult it is for learners to work with auxiliary answers and verbs like have to or want to. Maybe they have never had to actually teach these spoken forms...

I just do not understand why my answer was not upvoted and selected.

Questions and answers using an auxiliary:

Do you work?
Answer:
Yes, I work OR Yes, I do.
No, I don't work. OR No, I don't.

The present simple is used for something habitual or generally true.
It is not grammatical to use an adverb like there ("Do you work there?") and answer: Yes, I work.

Do you work there?
Answer:
Yes, I work there. OR Yes, I do.

For: "Do you have to do it", the standard answer with an auxiliary is:

Yes, I do.

However, there is this:
We do say: Yes, I have to [do it]. The do it is implied. It is a shortened form of: Yes, I have to do it. In English, certain verbs do not require the repetition of the main verb as an answer to a question OR continuing a discussion where these main verbs are implied. Some of them are: want, like, hate, prefer, have to do something.
Imagine a dialogue:
John: I think he said he has to do that job before next week.
Tom: Yes, he did [say it]. But he doesn't have to [do it] today.
John: Are you sure he doesn't though? [doesn't have to do it before next week].
Tom: Yes, I am. He doesn't have to but he can if he wants to.
The dialogue is an example of how people really speak. You can see how tricky the auxiliary is, coupled with verbs like want to [do something] and have to [do something].
There are two different things going on in the question. One is the strictly structured answer with an auxiliary and the other is how certain verbs (have, want, take, like, etc.) that "take to" work.

Do you really want to go or do you actually have to?
Answers:
No, I don't want to.
Yes, I have to.

For example.

Disregard the downvote. :)

"Do you run" I run or I do  but "Do you run a lot" an answer like "I run" would be strange?

@user203412 I have explained that in my answer. Why are you repeating the same question with a different verb and adverb? The reason stands. If you have a main action verb plus an adverb, we don't answer with just the main verb. Look at Stuart F's comment. He is saying the same thing as I am.

there is really no difference between answering to "do you run?" "Yes, I run and Yes, I do" both equally good?

@user203412 Asked by you and answered by me: Yes, I work OR Yes, I do. So, Yes, I run. OR Yes, I do. Third time.

Let's consider the two questions and the responses :


Do you work there" and my response is "Yes, I work" not "Yes, I do".
Another example "Do you have to do it" and I answer "Yes, I have to" not "Yes, I do"?


In the first case, the answer is not clear because the speaker asked the location of work. So the correct answer is:
"Yes, I work there." or
"Yes, I do."
In the second case
"Yes, I have to." is commonly used in the UK.
"Yes I do." is common in the US (meaning I do have to).

You will find American speakers often reply to 'have to' questions using 'do', while British speakers dom so much less often.

I'm with @MichaelHarvey on this. As an NZ English speaker, Yes I do (meaning I do have to) sounds entirely natural.

@PeterKirkpatrick What Michael Harvey' said was - British - I have to; American - I do. It means you are following the Americans and not Michael Harvey (UK)

@JamesMathai - yes, that's right, (AmE do, BrE, have) but I should emphasise that these are tendencies, not iron-clad rules (like most of such 'differences') and you will find people on either side of the divide who defy the tendency.

I fully understand what Michael was saying. My comment was in support of his analysis, not assessing what he personally might choose to say. And the key point here is that you said Yes I do is wrong. Both of us are responding to that assertion, which needs to be more nuanced.

@MichaelHarvey I shall include it in my answer.

Your second case assertion is completely wrong, I'm afraid.

@Lambie - are you sure? Why? The Brit part is OK. We might equally well say 'Yes', 'Yes, I have to', 'Yes, I do', or 'Yes, I do have to'. Probably more are possible.,

@MichaelHarvey This is wrong""Yes, I have to." is commonly used in the UK.
"Yes I do." is common in the US (meaning I do have to). They are both common in both for the reasons I give in my answer. Ergo, it's an inaccurate statement. There's a difference between them but it's not an AmE/BrE "thing".

"I do" means accepting all the conditions: - I take thee to be my wedded husband,
to have and to hold, from this day forward,
for better, for worse,
for richer, for poorer,
in sickness and in health,
to love and to cherish,
till death do us part,
according to God’s holy ordinance.
And thereto I pledge my faith.”

Your second statement is false. I do and I have to are common in AmE and BrE.

@Lambie What is the point in writing the same comment again?. You have received the reply from Michael Harvey'. In India, we follow UK grammar.

Michael Harvey is just being hard headed. Both are fine. Both are fine in the UK and in NA English. So,  you saying: We follow UK grammar means nothing. The grammars are the same in both.
